# jquery mobile collapsible-set perform jquery function on collapse

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to implement an action on collapse/expand of jquery mobile collapsible-set. I'm running jquery.mobile-1.4.4 and jquery-1.11.0.

I've posted code on fiddle to test if it works but it does not. This feature worked on older versions of jquery mobile and jquery.

http://jsfiddle.net/6txWy/

HTLM:

```
<div id="football" data-role="collapsible-set">

<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
<h3>Section 1</h3>
<p>I'm the collapsible set content for section 1.</p>
</div>

<div data-role="collapsible">
<h3>Section 2</h3>
<p>I'm the collapsible set content for section 2.</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#football').bind('expand', function () {
alert('Expanded');
}).bind('collapse', function () {
    alert('Collapsed');
});
```

Does anyone know of a way to achieve what I'm trying to do??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of jQuery Mobile 1.4, `expand` and `collapse` events are deprecated and replaced with `collapsibleexpand` and `collapsiblecollapse`.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function () {
   $(".selector").on("collapsibleexpand collapsiblecollapse", function () {
      /* code */
   });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/eo495k4z/)**